# MS Project custom buttons only firing if VBA editor open

Tags: vba, ms-project

I have some macros in MS Project that have buttons assigned. However, on some users' computers, I have them set up the buttons, but the buttons don't run the macro unless the VBA editor is open. I tried assigning keyboard shortcuts to run the macro, and the exact same problem comes up.
Is there any setting that would require the VBA editor to be open for the macros to fire for some users? Is there a known way around it?

Comment: Are you adding the buttons programmatically?

Comment: No, I'm using the "Customize the Ribbon" dialog, but if I export the XML, they do call out the right macros.

Comment: hmm, not sure, but sounds like it might be a namespace bug in the XML that the wizard is generating. Better to craft your own, or optimize the XML made by the wizard.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add "_Click" to the procedure name that the button calls? I've seen some posts where that made a difference.